# Finding Duplicate Entry from multiple table in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

I have three tables having following structure

Table Name : users

```
id        name      age
1         Alok       26
2         Ashok      28
3         Amit       25
```

Table Name : Departments

```
id        name      d_name
1         Alok       Ops
2         Amit       IT
3         Shekahr    CS
```

I want duplicate name with total count as following using mysql query

```
   total     name
   2         Alok
   2         Amit
   1         Ashok
   1         Shekhar
```

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*) as total,name  from (
select name from users
union 
all select * from deepartment ) as temp
group by name
```

`Union all` will merge your tables and with `group by` and `count` you should get the expected result.